# Inspect python module variable assignment source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, inspect

I'm inspecting a python module using `ast` and `inspect`. I need to get the source code of the nodes. I can read classes and functions, but variables I did't figure out a way.

If I have for example an assignment like this:

```
VAR = 10 * 2
```

I can get VAR and 20, but I need the source. The same happens for comprehensions, generators, etc.

Is there a way to do that without opening the module file as a text?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you open the module "as a text"? Could you give a bit more context? The best option is just to parse the source code.

Comment: It's an option, but  it's more than just "getsourcecode". I need to handle generators, multiple line statements..